# get all <a> tags href in page with php

Tags: php, web-crawler

i am trying to get all external links in one web page and store it in database.
i put all web page contents in variable:

```
$pageContent = file_get_contents("http://sample-site.org");
```

how i can save all external links??

for example if web page has a code such as:

```
<a href="http://othersite.com">other site</a>
```

i want to save http://othersite.com in database.
in the other words i want to make a crawler that store all external links exists in one web page.
how i can do this?

Answer (score 4):

You could use [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)'s `find` method:

```
require_once("simple_html_dom.php");
$pageContent = file_get_html("http://sample-site.org");
foreach ($pageContent->find("a") as $anchor)
    echo $anchor->href . "<br>";
```

Comment: Elegant. Bravissimo. +1

Comment: Are you sure that `file_get_contents()` is correct?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus you're right: I have replaced `file_get_contents` with `file_get_html`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [DOMDocument()](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and [DOMXPath()](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php).  This allows the result to only contain external links as you've requested.

As a note.  If you're going to crawl websites, you will more likely want to use [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php), but I will continue with [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) as that's what you're using in this example.  cURL would allow you to do things like set a user agent, headers, store cookies, etc. and appear more like a real user.  Some websites will attempt to prevent robots.

```
$html = file_get_contents("http://example.com");

$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc -> loadHTML($html);
$xp = new DOMXPath($doc);

// Only pull back A tags with an href attribute starting with "http".
$res = $xp -> query('//a[starts-with(@href, "http")]/@href');

if ($res -> length > 0)
{
    foreach ($res as $node)
    {
        echo "External Link: " . $node -> nodeValue . "\n";
    }
}
else
    echo "There were no external links found.";

/*
 * Output:
 *  External Link: http://www.iana.org/domains/example
 */
```